# iOS and mPOS Terminals - Contactless Payment

Tags: ios, swift, nfc

Everywhere i am reading that it is not possible to write data in iOS Swift or ObjectiveC via NFC. What about handling a contactless payment process? Is this even possible without using Apple Pay? If not is there any workaround which enables “NFC Writing” for iOS, because NfCCore doesnt provide it yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple keeps the NFC functionality closed, so only Apple Pay is allowed to function. Other than reading NDEF tags, no apps can use the phone's hardware either to work as an NFC reader (for example to top-up balance for a public transit contactless card) or to emulate a contactless card, either purely in software or using the phone's embedded secure element.

As far as I know (Apple as always does not say much), the latest iPhones' hardware is perfectly capable of doing all of the above, but some commercial decision resulted in keeping it unavailable for third party developers.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Any source for this please @mictter

Comment: Sources for the capabilities of iPhone's hardware: if they can make SE-based payments (ApplePay), they surely can run most contactless services. I usually see what Security Element they are using by looking at tear-downs of Apple HW such in iFixit's website.

Comment: can you please tell how to use the phone's embedded secure element? @mictter

Comment: I am afraid only Apple can - Apple Pay and the transit and university passes they are launching in the US are all implemented by Apple (or with Apple participating directly in the project). This is not very different to eSE in Android: there is no way you can access it without permission from the manufacturer.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it will be possible with iOS 13: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corenfc/creating_nfc_tags_from_your_iphone

Comment: The only issue is that using the device as a POS is not possible as core nfc doesn't let developers to interact with payment cards.